# Создание списка с колонками

Tags: c#, wpf

Появилась нужда сделать список с колонками, чтобы их размер можно было регулировать. Такие списки используются везде, но оказалось что, не все так просто. Возможно, я просто не понимаю как ввести поисковой запрос.

[image: Списки]

Comment: ListView с GridView и DataGrid умеют это штатно

Comment: Вот тут всё подробно описано: https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/5.14.php

Comment: Ааааа! Только не DataGrid!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Два варианта на выбор:

#### List View с Grid View внутри

Больше подходит для отображения данных:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Имя" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Дата" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Тип" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Размер" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Size}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### DataGrid

Больше подходит под сценарии inline edit, чем под обычное отображение списка.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}">

</DataGrid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]